# Hypernyms for directions

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I am searching for hypernyms to summarise and differentiate between two groups words describing possible movement directions in a 2D space.

1. `up, down, left, right`
2. `up-left, up-right, down-left, down-right`

The criteria for the hypernyms are - in order of importance: 1) Discriminative, 2) Descriptive and 3) Concise/brief

The hierarchy I came up with so far looks like:

```
               Direction
              /         \
 Simple direction     Composite direction
     (group 1)              (group 2)
```

While simple/composite work reasonably well to differentiate between the two groups they aren't very descriptive of the group they represent. This made me wonder about better terms.

Comment: You left out Group 3: *up-left-forward, up-right-forward, down-left-forward, down-right-forward, up-left-backward, up-right-backward, down-left-backward, down-right-backward.*

Comment: Who uses your second group of directions? Did you make it up? I don't think anyone really thinks of those as directions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well that's for when moving to 3D!

Comment: @curiousdannii The upper edge of a rectangle, the upper-left corner of a rectangle - what terms would you use?

Comment: Upper left is very different from up-left!

Comment: @curiousdannii Well you can imagine, if you are in the center of a rectangle and you move up you get to the upper edge and if you move up-left you get to the upper-left/top-left corner. But the direction you move in is up-left then, right?

Comment: I'm no mathematician, but I'd have thought you could reasonably call OP's "composite" directions ***vectors***, since they have two independent variables.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You could call them vectors but then its hard to discriminate between the two groups because "UP" would just be a vector with no horizontal component.

Comment: @curiousdannii I edited the question to make it clearer what the purpose of these "directions" is.

Comment: @Samuel: Not at all - "UP" is a *direction*, because it's fully specified by just ***one variable***. In that context I'd be happy to call "UP-LEFT" a *vector* because as I said, it requires ***two variables***.

Comment: @Samuel upper-left is a *side* or *corner* you reach by moving in two directions: up and left. I see no evidence that speakers of English conceptualise it as moving in one direction (up-left). This is different from compass directions where north-east is a legitimate direction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I like the focus on made up by *one* or *two* components, but if you use it in a sentence it might be confusing: If you are at the center of a rectangle and you choose to move in any *direction* you will arrive at an edge, while if you move according to a *vector* you will arrive at a corner.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree with the OP, from a math/engineering point of view, in a domain where there are two dimensions, it doesn't make much sense to say that "up" is not a vector just because its horizontal component is zero. In 3D graphics or robotics, "up" is pretty much always treated as a vector of 2 (or 3 or more) components, rather than as a different type of object from "up-left".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - you could implement all directions as a vector pair, and the group 1 directions have a 0 element, and the Group 2 have both elements the same.  Then there is no difference in the variable type, just a restriction in its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sure does sound like homework.

Anyway, in the case of a [dpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-pad), the four "simple directions" are simply called *directionals*, and the four "composite directions" are called *diagonals*.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It's not homework though, its for a robotics tool ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could use an analogy with compass directions.

North, South, East and West are the *Cardinal Directions*.  These would align with Up, Down, Left and Right.

Other directions such as North-East, aligning with Up-Right are *Intercardinal Directions*.

Comment: I like "cardinal" - it seems both discriminative and descriptive. "Intercardinal" may be discriminative but it's not intuitive. @OP, what about "cardinal" vs. "compound" directions?

Comment: @LarsH That is pretty good, cardinal gives the sense of "basic directions" and compound clearly describes the concept of a direction made up of multiple cardinal directions!

Comment: Traditionally, what Chenmunka refers to as intercardinal directions have been known as ordinal directions.